# adding strings to array spaces will look like weird symbol

Tags: c#

So I am importing strings to a string list.
And some of the strings contain spaces.
The spaces will look like the following when added into the list.

I�H1t�HAr�D

How can I fix this?

Comment: tabs? nulls? you should be able to tell in the debugger

Comment: Importing from where? you'll need to explain your question a bit more, see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you provide some more information???

Comment: The source from where you read the strings, reads the content with the wrong encoding.

Comment: @Oliver Is right, maybe look at what Unicode values the `chars` have.

Comment: You need to add the source code. You are probably using the wrong encoding, but nobody will know unless you provide your code.